# How do I update an entry in MySQL using CASE for the new value?

Tags: mysql

Can anybody tell me how to fix this query?

```
update ae44
set Price = Case
when ID = 'AT259793380' then '500'
when ID = 'AT271729590' then '600'
when ID = 'AT275981020' then '700'
end case
```

I just want to mass update listing price based on ID by matching up ID.

Comment: You need to ask questions with detail. Whats wrong with it?

Comment: better run separate queries. This one will lock the entire table

Comment: I had a similar problem, this post put me in the right direction (upvoted Quassnoi!), but be VERY careful with this, use a WHERE statement as well, otherwise the entire table will get price=NULL if it's not one of the 3 stated ID's

Answer (score 40, accepted):

```
UPDATE  ae44
SET     price =
        CASE
        WHEN ID = 'AT259793380' THEN
                '500'
        WHEN ID = 'AT271729590' THEN
                '600'
        WHEN ID = 'AT275981020' THEN
                '700'
        END
```

Note than this query will update prices for the records with other ids to `NULL`.

If you only want to update only ids from your list, use this:

```
UPDATE  ae44
JOIN    (
        SELECT  'AT259793380' AS oldval, '500' AS newval
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  'AT271729590' AS oldval, '600' AS newval
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  'AT275981020' AS oldval, '700' AS newval
        ) q
ON      ae44.id = q.oldval
SET     price = q.newval
```

Comment: I did try that, it keeps coming back with Price cannot be null (because i have it set that way)

Comment: Might want to add en explicit "else" for any other cases.

Comment: Or maybe just add a where clause to only update the items that match your specified IDs

Comment: @Mike: this was not obvious from your query.

Comment: okay, i'm sorry, i thought it would be cause i'm saying when columnd ID = 'whatever' price = '500'

Comment: @Mike: it's obvious what to do when the id is `whatever`. It's not obvious what to do when it's not. Do you want to leave it as is, update to a default value or what?

Comment: I would just want to leave all rows as they are and only update the rows which i have an ID value for

Comment: @Mike: then use my second query.

Comment: okay, i saw the first error it tells me 0 rows were effected.

Comment: @Mike: what version of `MySQL` are you using?

Comment: I misstypes a } for a ), so i fixed that and i got 0 rows effected, i'm using the latest version, downloaded it last week

Comment: @Mike: check your data then. The query itself works as long as there are records with given ids in `ae44`.

Comment: ugh, n/m found it, you get the answer, i need to sleep.  TY

Answer (score 27):

```
UPDATE ae44 SET
    Price = CASE
    WHEN ID = 'AT259793380' THEN '500'
    WHEN ID = 'AT271729590' THEN '600'
    WHEN ID = 'AT275981020' THEN '700'
    ELSE Price END
```

Or you can use WHERE:

```
UPDATE ae44 SET
    Price = CASE
    WHEN ID = 'AT259793380' THEN '500'
    WHEN ID = 'AT271729590' THEN '600'
    WHEN ID = 'AT275981020' THEN '700'
    END
WHERE 
    ID IN ('AT259793380', 'AT271729590', 'AT275981020')
```

And set the LIMIT is good idea too:

```
UPDATE ae44 SET
    Price = CASE
    WHEN ID = 'AT259793380' THEN '500'
    WHEN ID = 'AT271729590' THEN '600'
    WHEN ID = 'AT275981020' THEN '700'
    END
WHERE 
    ID IN ('AT259793380', 'AT271729590', 'AT275981020')
LIMIT 3
```

Answer (score 4):

Remove the second "case" and it will work:

```
UPDATE ae44
SET Price = (CASE
WHEN ID = 'AT259793380' THEN '500'
WHEN ID = 'AT271729590' THEN '600'
WHEN ID = 'AT275981020' THEN '700'
END)
```

Comment: Be careful with this... it will set the price of any other item in the database to NULL. Add a where statement (set price is (case...) where id in ("AT259793380","AT271729590","AT275981020"))

Answer (score 3):

You can try a simple query like:

```
UPDATE `table`
SET Price = ELT(field(ID,'AT259793380','AT271729590','AT275981020'), '500', '600', '700')
WHERE ID IN ('AT259793380','AT271729590','AT275981020')
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming this is a mysql query. You can use the first query that Quassnoi posted and just add

```
WHEN ID THEN price
```

as the last "WHEN". This will prevent all of your price fields from being set to null

```
UPDATE  ae44
    SET price =
    CASE
    WHEN ID = 'AT259793380' THEN '500'
    WHEN ID = 'AT271729590' THEN '600'
    WHEN ID = 'AT275981020' THEN '700'
    WHEN ID THEN price
    END
```

Comment: +1 Cool alternative _dooplenty_, but isn't it better to restrict the update to the rows that you really want to update instead of all of them?

Answer (score 0):

Checking the mysql error would have revealed:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
> corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
> near '= 'AT275981020' then '700' end case'

I don't know if you thought you could write `case` as an alias or what that alias could be used for.  Maybe this was just bad copy-pasta from another `CASE` block that you found in a `SELECT` query.

Ultimately it was the trailing `case` that was the issue.  The query will execute once that final word is removed, but there is more to explain.

In my own project, I would be using the more concise variant of `CASE` syntax with `ID` only written once instead of writing mostly redundant expressions in each case.

I also recommend using lowercase column names so that the sql is easier to read for humans.

```
UPDATE ae44 SET
Price = CASE ID
    WHEN 'AT259793380' THEN '500'
    WHEN 'AT271729590' THEN '600'
    WHEN 'AT275981020' THEN '700'
END
WHERE 
    ID IN ('AT259793380','AT271729590','AT275981020')
```

With the addition of the `WHERE` cause, only 3 rows will be whitelisted for possible modification -- as a consequence the `ELSE` can be safely omitted from the `CASE` block.

Answer (score -2):

```
update ae44
set Price = 
Case ID
when 'AT259793380' then '500'
when 'AT271729590' then '600'
when 'AT275981020' then '700'
end case
```

Comment: This piece of code is a copy of the question's code with a `case ID when` syntax instead of a `case when ID =` syntax and does not answer the question, since it did not fix the syntax error for having `end case` (the last `case` was the problem) and will update all the other rows' Price field to `NULL`.