# MySQL conditionally UPDATE rows' boolean column values based on a whitelist of ids

Tags: mysql, sql-update, boolean, conditional-statements, case

I'm trying to update a set of records (*`boolean` fields*) in a single query if possible.

The input is coming from paginated radio controls, so a given `POST` will have the page's worth of IDs with a `true` or `false` value.

I was trying to go this direction:

```
UPDATE my_table
    SET field = CASE
        WHEN id IN (/* true ids */) THEN TRUE
        WHEN id IN (/* false ids */) THEN FALSE
    END
```

But this resulted in the "true id" rows being updated to `true`, and **ALL** other rows were updated to `false`.

I assume I've made some gross syntactical error, or perhaps that I'm approaching this incorrectly.

Any thoughts on a solution?

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL update case help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6734231/mysql-update-case-help)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Didn't you forget to do an "ELSE" in the case statement?

```
UPDATE my_table
    SET field = CASE
        WHEN id IN (/* true ids */) THEN TRUE
        WHEN id IN (/* false ids */) THEN FALSE
        ELSE field=field 
    END
```

Without the ELSE, I assume the evaluation chain stops at the last WHEN and executes that update. Also, you are not limiting the rows that you are trying to update; if you don't do the ELSE you should at least tell the update to only update the rows you want and not all the rows (as you are doing). Look at the WHERE clause below:

```
  UPDATE my_table
        SET field = CASE
            WHEN id IN (/* true ids */) THEN TRUE
            WHEN id IN (/* false ids */) THEN FALSE
        END
  WHERE id in (true ids + false_ids)
```

Comment: Thanks @Icarus - The second solution you posted is perfect. While the first one works of course, MySQL matches every row in the table; that seems liable to cause performance loss in larger tables (*10^6 rows or more*) despite the fact that it only actually updates the rows that have changed. Can you shed some light on this? (*the condition on a union of all targeted IDs is a clean enough solution, but I'm just curious*)

Comment: @TomcatExodus: I am not sure I quite understand your question but, in general, if you have an update with no where clause the database engine will almost certainly have to perform a table scan and will hurt performance, specially on big tables. So yes, having the where clause in there should be faster but only if the id column is also an index. If it isn't, the table scan is unavoidable.

Comment: Ok @Icarus - That's what I meant, the `id` column is indexed. I was referring to the output stream; without the `WHERE` clause, I get several thousands of rows matched, but only a handful are affected. The thousands being matched is the full table scan that I'd like to avoid, and *is* avoided by applying a `WHERE` clause, specifying only a union of true/false ids. Just wanted some clarification. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the tip, it appear simple but it's something that anybody can ommit!

Answer (score 7):

You can avoid field = field

```
update my_table
    set field = case
        when id in (....) then true
        when id in (...) then false
        else field
    end
```

Comment: Thanks @nick rulez - The `field = field` seemed odd at first glance too (*field = field = field?*)

Answer (score 0):

**You can avoid the use of a case block for this task** because you are setting a conditional boolean value.

Declare all `id`s that should be changed in the `WHERE` clause.

Declare all of the `true` `id` values in the `SET` clause's `IN()` condition.  If any given `id` is found in the `IN` then the boolean value will become `true`, else `false`.

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/512732/2/0)

```
TABLE `my_table` (
  `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `my_boolean` boolean
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
ALTER TABLE `my_table`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);
  
INSERT INTO `my_table` VALUES
(1,true),
(2,false),
(3,true),
(4,false),
(5,true),
(6,false);

UPDATE my_table
SET my_boolean = (id IN (2,4))
WHERE id IN (2,3);

SELECT * FROM my_table;
```

Output:

```
id  my_boolean
1   true
2   true       #changed
3   false      #changed
4   false
5   true
6   false
```