# list all column names which are updated

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, sql-update, prepared-statement

What I have is below table.

```
+----+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| id |  val1  |  val2  |  val3  |  val4  |
+====+========+========+========+========+
| 1  |  data1 |  data2 |  data3 |  data4 |
+----+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

Now I fire a query with below details, say

```
UPDATE tableName 
SET val1='newVal1', val2='data2', val3='data3', val4='data4' 
WHERE id=1
```

**Note:** This is just same query. Actually I am implementing edit from four text field. So  what I would be having using JSF and Java bean would be as below.

```
PreparedStatement psmt = conn.prepareStatement("
    UPDATE tableName 
    SET val1=?, val2=?, val3=?, val4=? 
    WHERE id=1
");
psmt.setString(1, myValue1);
psmt.setString(2, myValue2);
psmt.setString(3, myValue3);
psmt.setString(4, myValue4);
psmt.execute();
```

What I want is using above query, which columns are updated. In above case, `val1` column is updated.

Basically I want this for log purpose where I would come to know who did the edit and what edit is done. Any idea/ suggestion how to get this done?

**Note:** ***I don't want to create any other table as stated in answer by meewoK. Just using query, I would like to know the column names which are updated.***

---

**I will explain what I want with example.**

Let's say **userA** gets logged in into the system. Now he has access of user lists. Now let's say he did edit for **User B**. What he changed is User B, email id and full name.
Now in log what I want is two entries.

```
=================================================================
whoDid  whatDid forWhom   whichField   whichSection whatTime
=================================================================
userA   edit    userB     emailId      User         time_whenDid
userA   edit    userB     fullName     User         time_whenDid
=================================================================
```

Comment: @MahmoudGamal : I tried to write update statement in one query only. Actually I have 32 fields in one form and writing 32 query for each field separately is ugly. Also in this example I know only 1 field is going to update. But programmatically, I will not come to know which field to update.

Comment: @MahmoudGamal : Do you meant, I should compare the old val1 data with new val1 data and then write the update query if they are different?

Comment: Check your fields from the front end application to figure out which column is updated with a new value, then do `UPDATE` for those fields having the new value.

Comment: @Alya'aGamal : this way I feel its is lengthy process to edit the data as first I will compare the data and then process the edit work. also it is increasing programming burden.

Comment: @MahmoudGamal : Exactly. With the above statement, I want to know which columns are updated. That's it.

Comment: It is not lengthy process, you already should read the values when displaying them on the form fields, then check the fields' old values and the new values when pressing the update button, and then update only the field that was has a new value.

Comment: @Alya'aGamal : I am using JSF/ Java and there I believe I will have to create two variable for each field. and then compare.... so one statement with all 32 field is good option. Hence I was looking for a way where mysql can tell me which columns are updated.

Comment: It seems like @MahmoudGamal has a point, my solution will require extra work, I think it would be better and easier to do one `UPDATE` statement only .

Comment: @MahmoudGamal : My client want to know who did the edit and what edit he did. For that I would like to know which fields are edited..

Comment: What about to make another table with the new values?? , then you can track which column is updated ??!!

Comment: So basically, you want to update the fields, and list only the fields which are as a result different from the previous fields?

Comment: @meewoK : Yes, but row would be same and it would be already updated. So I can't compare two rows..

Comment: @Alya'aGamal : Why new table? Why more programming?

Comment: Why do you want to store which values were changed? As a log or record of changes?

Comment: @meewoK : Yes, for log purpose.. My Client would like to know who did the edit and what edit did that user did... so I want this for log purpose.

Comment: @Fahim Parkar , provided an answer on using UPDATABLE VIEW, and Conditionals in Update to log to second table. Stored Procedure would also be an interesting approach.

Comment: @Fahim Parkar how are poeple logging in with the java application is that a mysql username and password or...

Comment: @RaymondN : with username and password...

Comment: @Fahim Parkar Yes but is that a MySQL username and password or it it just a account username and password?

Comment: @RaymondN : Obviously the username is stored in database. I want to track the username with which login is done and edit done by that user...

Comment: Do you need a log only for the last change or a log history?

Comment: @FahimParkar I'm sorry if this is a stupid question, but where is the log stored? In the database or somewhere else?

Comment: @durron597 : obviously database...

Comment: Ummm, is there any reason that a trigger on the table that gets updated has not been mentioned? This seems like the perfect scenario for a trigger.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about running something like the following query to create the log entry **just before** the update:

```
PreparedStatement psmt = conn.prepareStatement("
    SELECT CASE WHEN val1 = ?
                THEN ''
                ELSE 'val1 changed from ' + val1 + ' to ' + ? + '\n'
           END CASE +
           CASE WHEN val2 = ?
                THEN ''
                ELSE 'val2 changed from ' + val2 + ' to ' + ? + '\n'
           END CASE +
           CASE WHEN val3 = ?
                THEN ''
                ELSE 'val3 changed from ' + val3 + ' to ' + ? + '\n'
           END CASE +
           CASE WHEN val4 = ?
                THEN ''
                ELSE 'val4 changed from ' + val4 + ' to ' + ? + '\n'
           END CASE AS logentry
    FROM tableName
    WHERE id=1
");
psmt.setString(1, myValue1);
psmt.setString(2, myValue1);
psmt.setString(3, myValue2);
psmt.setString(4, myValue2);
psmt.setString(5, myValue3);
psmt.setString(6, myValue3);
psmt.setString(7, myValue4);
psmt.setString(8, myValue4);
ResultSet rs = psmt.executeQuery();
String logentry = rs.getString("logentry");
```

**Disclaimer:** This is off the top of my head and completely untested so may need a bit of tweaking - should be enough to get you going though.

**Possible issue:** Even if you execute the query just before the update there's a chance data may have changed between the two. Depending on various factors this may or may not be an issue in practice but it's worth mentioning.

Comment: I will check this and get back to you tomorrow.

Comment: not checked yet... will do that soon... got stucked in another work... sorry for late reply... i will accept once done..

Comment: not yet... busy in another jobs... But once done, I will update you... but I think this idea will ROCK.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this code. It stores logging in Storage class. You may modify the storage to suit your requirement. This code only works if the db is accessed by **single** jvm. I have not tested this code, so I welcome correction.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    PreparedStatement psmt = new LoggingPreparedStatement(conn.prepareStatement(
            " UPDATE tableName SET val1 =?,val2 =?,val3 =?,val4 =? WHERE id = 1 "));
    psmt.setString(1, myValue1);
    psmt.setString(2, myValue2);
    psmt.setString(3, myValue3);
    psmt.setString(4, myValue4);
    psmt.execute();

    for (Trail trail : Storage.INSTANCE.getTrails()) {
        System.out.println(trail);
    }
}

public static class Trail {
    private final int fieldIdx;
    private final String prevValue;
    private final String currentValue;

    private Trail(int fieldIdx, String prevValue, String currentValue) {
        this.fieldIdx = fieldIdx;
        this.prevValue = prevValue;
        this.currentValue = currentValue;
    }

    public int getFieldIdx() {
        return fieldIdx;
    }

    public String getPrevValue() {
        return prevValue;
    }

    public String getCurrentValue() {
        return currentValue;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Trail{" +
                "fieldIdx=" + fieldIdx +
                ", prevValue='" + prevValue + '\'' +
                ", currentValue='" + currentValue + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}

public enum Storage {
    INSTANCE;

    private final ConcurrentMap<Integer, String> lastValues = new ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, String>();
    private final Queue<Trail> trails = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Trail>();
    private final Object lock = new Object();

    public void putTrailIfNecessary(int idx, String newValue) {
        String lastValue = lastValues.get(idx);
        if (lastValue == null ? newValue != null : !lastValue.equals(newValue)) {
            synchronized (lock) {
                String lastValue1 = lastValues.get(idx);
                if (lastValue1 == null ? newValue != null : !lastValue1.equals(newValue)) {
                    lastValues.put(idx, newValue);
                    trails.add(new Trail(idx, lastValue1, newValue));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public List<Trail> getTrails() {
        return new ArrayList<Trail>(trails);
    }
}

public static class LoggingPreparedStatement
        implements PreparedStatement {
    private final PreparedStatement delegate;

    public LoggingPreparedStatement(PreparedStatement delegate) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }

    // this we put audit trail
    @Override
    public void setString(int parameterIndex, String x)
            throws SQLException {
        Storage.INSTANCE.putTrailIfNecessary(parameterIndex, x);
        delegate.setString(parameterIndex, x);
    }

    @Override
    public ResultSet executeQuery()
            throws SQLException {return delegate.executeQuery();}

    @Override
    public int executeUpdate()
            throws SQLException {return delegate.executeUpdate();}

    @Override
    public void setNull(int parameterIndex, int sqlType)
            throws SQLException {delegate.setNull(parameterIndex, sqlType);}

    @Override
    public void setBoolean(int parameterIndex, boolean x)
            throws SQLException {delegate.setBoolean(parameterIndex, x);}

    @Override
    public void setByte(int parameterIndex, byte x)
            throws SQLException {delegate.setByte(parameterIndex, x);}

    @Override
    public void setShort(int parameterIndex, short x)
            throws SQLException {delegate.setShort(parameterIndex, x);}

    @Override
    public void setInt(int parameterIndex, int x)
            throws SQLException {delegate.setInt(parameterIndex, x);}

    @Override
    public void setLong(int parameterIndex, long x)
            throws SQLException {delegate.setLong(parameterIndex, x);}

    @Override
    public void setFloat(int parameterIndex, float x)
            throws SQLException {delegate.setFloat(parameterIndex, x);}

    @Override
    public void setDouble(int parameterIndex, double x)
            throws SQLException {delegate.setDouble(parameterIndex, x);}

    @Override
    public void setBigDecimal(int parameterIndex, BigDecimal x)
            throws SQLException {delegate.setBigDecimal(parameterIndex, x);}

    @Override
    public void setBytes(int parameterIndex, byte[] x)
            throws SQLException {delegate.setBytes(parameterIndex, x);}

    @Override
    public void setDate(int parameterIndex, Date x)
            throws SQLException {delegate.setDate(parameterIndex, x);}

    @Override
    public void setTime(int parameterIndex, Time x)
            throws SQLException {delegate.setTime(parameterIndex, x);}

    @Override
    public void setTimestamp(int parameterIndex,
            Timestamp x)
            throws SQLException {delegate.setTimestamp(parameterIndex, x);}

    @Override
    public void setAsciiStream(int parameterIndex, InputStream x, int length)
            throws SQLException {delegate.setAsciiStream(parameterIndex, x, length);}

    @Override
    public void setUnicodeStream(int parameterIndex, InputStream x, int length)
            throws SQLException {delegate.setUnicodeStream(parameterIndex, x, length);}

    @Override
    public void setBinaryStream(int parameterIndex, InputStream x, int length)
            throws SQLException {delegate.setBinaryStream(parameterIndex, x, length);}

    @Override
    public void clearParameters()
            throws SQLException {delegate.clearParameters();}

    @Override
    public void setObject(int parameterIndex, Object x, int targetSqlType)
            throws SQLException {delegate.setObject(parameterIndex, x, targetSqlType);}

    @Override
    public void setObject(int parameterIndex, Object x)
            throws SQLException {delegate.setObject(parameterIndex, x);}

    @Override
    public boolean execute()
            throws SQLException {return delegate.execute();}

    @Override
    public void addBatch()
            throws SQLException {delegate.addBatch();}

    @Override
    public void setCharacterStream(int parameterIndex, Reader reader, int length)
            throws SQLException {delegate.setCharacterStream(parameterIndex, reader, length);}

    @Override
    public void setRef(int parameterIndex, Ref x)
            throws SQLException {delegate.setRef(parameterIndex, x);}

    @Override
    public void setBlob(int parameterIndex, Blob x)
            throws SQLException {delegate.setBlob(parameterIndex, x);}

    @Override
    public void setClob(int parameterIndex, Clob x)
            throws SQLException {delegate.setClob(parameterIndex, x);}

    @Override
    public void setArray(int parameterIndex, Array x)
            throws SQLException {delegate.setArray(parameterIndex, x);}

    @Override
    public ResultSetMetaData getMetaData()
            throws SQLException {return delegate.getMetaData();}

    @Override
    public void setDate(int parameterIndex, Date x, Calendar cal)
            throws SQLException {delegate.setDate(parameterIndex, x, cal);}

    @Override
    public void setTime(int parameterIndex, Time x, Calendar cal)
            throws SQLException {delegate.setTime(parameterIndex, x, cal);}

    @Override
    public void setTimestamp(int parameterIndex, Timestamp x, Calendar cal)
            throws SQLException {delegate.setTimestamp(parameterIndex, x, cal);}

    @Override
    public void setNull(int parameterIndex, int sqlType, String typeName)
            throws SQLException {delegate.setNull(parameterIndex, sqlType, typeName);}

    @Override
    public void setURL(int parameterIndex, URL x)
            throws SQLException {delegate.setURL(parameterIndex, x);}

    @Override
    public ParameterMetaData getParameterMetaData()
            throws SQLException {return delegate.getParameterMetaData();}

    @Override
    public void setRowId(int parameterIndex, RowId x)
            throws SQLException {delegate.setRowId(parameterIndex, x);}

    @Override
    public void setNString(int parameterIndex, String value)
            throws SQLException {delegate.setNString(parameterIndex, value);}

    @Override
    public void setNCharacterStream(int parameterIndex, Reader value, long length)
            throws SQLException {delegate.setNCharacterStream(parameterIndex, value, length);}

    @Override
    public void setNClob(int parameterIndex, NClob value)
            throws SQLException {delegate.setNClob(parameterIndex, value);}

    @Override
    public void setClob(int parameterIndex, Reader reader, long length)
            throws SQLException {delegate.setClob(parameterIndex, reader, length);}

    @Override
    public void setBlob(int parameterIndex, InputStream inputStream, long length)
            throws SQLException {delegate.setBlob(parameterIndex, inputStream, length);}

    @Override
    public void setNClob(int parameterIndex, Reader reader, long length)
            throws SQLException {delegate.setNClob(parameterIndex, reader, length);}

    @Override
    public void setSQLXML(int parameterIndex, SQLXML xmlObject)
            throws SQLException {delegate.setSQLXML(parameterIndex, xmlObject);}

    @Override
    public void setObject(int parameterIndex, Object x, int targetSqlType, int scaleOrLength)
            throws SQLException {delegate.setObject(parameterIndex, x, targetSqlType, scaleOrLength);}

    @Override
    public void setAsciiStream(int parameterIndex, InputStream x, long length)
            throws SQLException {delegate.setAsciiStream(parameterIndex, x, length);}

    @Override
    public void setBinaryStream(int parameterIndex, InputStream x, long length)
            throws SQLException {delegate.setBinaryStream(parameterIndex, x, length);}

    @Override
    public void setCharacterStream(int parameterIndex, Reader reader, long length)
            throws SQLException {delegate.setCharacterStream(parameterIndex, reader, length);}

    @Override
    public void setAsciiStream(int parameterIndex, InputStream x)
            throws SQLException {delegate.setAsciiStream(parameterIndex, x);}

    @Override
    public void setBinaryStream(int parameterIndex, InputStream x)
            throws SQLException {delegate.setBinaryStream(parameterIndex, x);}

    @Override
    public void setCharacterStream(int parameterIndex, Reader reader)
            throws SQLException {delegate.setCharacterStream(parameterIndex, reader);}

    @Override
    public void setNCharacterStream(int parameterIndex, Reader value)
            throws SQLException {delegate.setNCharacterStream(parameterIndex, value);}

    @Override
    public void setClob(int parameterIndex, Reader reader)
            throws SQLException {delegate.setClob(parameterIndex, reader);}

    @Override
    public void setBlob(int parameterIndex, InputStream inputStream)
            throws SQLException {delegate.setBlob(parameterIndex, inputStream);}

    @Override
    public void setNClob(int parameterIndex, Reader reader)
            throws SQLException {delegate.setNClob(parameterIndex, reader);}

    @Override
    public ResultSet executeQuery(String sql)
            throws SQLException {return delegate.executeQuery(sql);}

    @Override
    public int executeUpdate(String sql)
            throws SQLException {return delegate.executeUpdate(sql);}

    @Override
    public void close()
            throws SQLException {delegate.close();}

    @Override
    public int getMaxFieldSize()
            throws SQLException {return delegate.getMaxFieldSize();}

    @Override
    public void setMaxFieldSize(int max)
            throws SQLException {delegate.setMaxFieldSize(max);}

    @Override
    public int getMaxRows()
            throws SQLException {return delegate.getMaxRows();}

    @Override
    public void setMaxRows(int max)
            throws SQLException {delegate.setMaxRows(max);}

    @Override
    public void setEscapeProcessing(boolean enable)
            throws SQLException {delegate.setEscapeProcessing(enable);}

    @Override
    public int getQueryTimeout()
            throws SQLException {return delegate.getQueryTimeout();}

    @Override
    public void setQueryTimeout(int seconds)
            throws SQLException {delegate.setQueryTimeout(seconds);}

    @Override
    public void cancel()
            throws SQLException {delegate.cancel();}

    @Override
    public SQLWarning getWarnings()
            throws SQLException {return delegate.getWarnings();}

    @Override
    public void clearWarnings()
            throws SQLException {delegate.clearWarnings();}

    @Override
    public void setCursorName(String name)
            throws SQLException {delegate.setCursorName(name);}

    @Override
    public boolean execute(String sql)
            throws SQLException {return delegate.execute(sql);}

    @Override
    public ResultSet getResultSet()
            throws SQLException {return delegate.getResultSet();}

    @Override
    public int getUpdateCount()
            throws SQLException {return delegate.getUpdateCount();}

    @Override
    public boolean getMoreResults()
            throws SQLException {return delegate.getMoreResults();}

    @Override
    public void setFetchDirection(int direction)
            throws SQLException {delegate.setFetchDirection(direction);}

    @Override
    public int getFetchDirection()
            throws SQLException {return delegate.getFetchDirection();}

    @Override
    public void setFetchSize(int rows)
            throws SQLException {delegate.setFetchSize(rows);}

    @Override
    public int getFetchSize()
            throws SQLException {return delegate.getFetchSize();}

    @Override
    public int getResultSetConcurrency()
            throws SQLException {return delegate.getResultSetConcurrency();}

    @Override
    public int getResultSetType()
            throws SQLException {return delegate.getResultSetType();}

    @Override
    public void addBatch(String sql)
            throws SQLException {delegate.addBatch(sql);}

    @Override
    public void clearBatch()
            throws SQLException {delegate.clearBatch();}

    @Override
    public int[] executeBatch()
            throws SQLException {return delegate.executeBatch();}

    @Override
    public Connection getConnection()
            throws SQLException {return delegate.getConnection();}

    @Override
    public boolean getMoreResults(int current)
            throws SQLException {return delegate.getMoreResults(current);}

    @Override
    public ResultSet getGeneratedKeys()
            throws SQLException {return delegate.getGeneratedKeys();}

    @Override
    public int executeUpdate(String sql, int autoGeneratedKeys)
            throws SQLException {return delegate.executeUpdate(sql, autoGeneratedKeys);}

    @Override
    public int executeUpdate(String sql, int[] columnIndexes)
            throws SQLException {return delegate.executeUpdate(sql, columnIndexes);}

    @Override
    public int executeUpdate(String sql, String[] columnNames)
            throws SQLException {return delegate.executeUpdate(sql, columnNames);}

    @Override
    public boolean execute(String sql, int autoGeneratedKeys)
            throws SQLException {return delegate.execute(sql, autoGeneratedKeys);}

    @Override
    public boolean execute(String sql, int[] columnIndexes)
            throws SQLException {return delegate.execute(sql, columnIndexes);}

    @Override
    public boolean execute(String sql, String[] columnNames)
            throws SQLException {return delegate.execute(sql, columnNames);}

    @Override
    public int getResultSetHoldability()
            throws SQLException {return delegate.getResultSetHoldability();}

    @Override
    public boolean isClosed()
            throws SQLException {return delegate.isClosed();}

    @Override
    public void setPoolable(boolean poolable)
            throws SQLException {delegate.setPoolable(poolable);}

    @Override
    public boolean isPoolable()
            throws SQLException {return delegate.isPoolable();}

    @Override
    public <T> T unwrap(Class<T> iface)
            throws SQLException {return delegate.unwrap(iface);}

    @Override
    public boolean isWrapperFor(Class<?> iface)
            throws SQLException {return delegate.isWrapperFor(iface);}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do one of the following:

1. Create a stored procedure within mysql which does the check and updates a second table.
2. Create an updateable view and use a [MySQL update conditions in one query (UPDATE, SET & CASE)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6975575/mysql-update-conditions-in-one-query-update-set-case) which will check if update value is different than current value and update a flag.
3. Do the check clientside, based on what original values were and which fields in client were changed.

If you really want to do it in once query, one interesting approach is Option 2...

### Option 2

**1) Create a second table called tableNamePrevious which has the following fields:**

```
+ id_prev +  val1_prev  +  val2_prev  +  val3_prev  +  val4_prev  ...
```

This table will store the previous values when a change is made. If no change is made (NULL) will be entered.

**2) Create an UPDATABLE view with the following query (following rules here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman//5.5/en/view-updatability.html)**

```
create view tableNameView as select * from tableName, tableNamePrevious where tableName.id = tableNamePrevious.id_prev;
```

**3) Run an update on the view, using conditions in update:**

```
update tableNameView 
    SET val1_prev = CASE
        WHEN val1 = INPUT_VAL1 THEN NULL
        WHEN NOT val1 = INPUT_VAL1 THEN val1
    END,
    val2_prev = CASE
        WHEN val2 = INPUT_VAL2 THEN NULL
        WHEN NOT val2 = INPUT_VAL2 THEN val2
    END,
    ... ,
    val1='newVal1', val2='data2', ... ,
    where id = INPUT_ID;
```

So, when the new INPUT_VALUE is not the same as the existing, the field in the second table will be the old value.
Otherwise it will be null.

Using the up datable view means you update both the table, and the log table containing the changes.

The case statements mean you can check that new input values, are not the same as previous.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using a trigger? This is based on the example from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_trigger#MySQL):

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER user_trigger
    BEFORE UPDATE ON user_table
    REFERENCING NEW ROW AS n, OLD ROW AS o
    FOR EACH ROW
    IF n.val1 <> o.val1 THEN
        INSERT INTO Log (whoDid, whatDid, ...) VALUES (..., 'edit', ...)
    END IF;
;
```