# Update MySql Field (if field is not empty, go to next one)

Tags: php, mysql

Hello I have table with 10 columns (columnA, ColumnB, ColumnC ...), ColumnA is for ID.

> I want to make an update in php in this way: **IF ColumnB is not empty then update ColumnC, if ColumnC is not empty update ColumnD** ...until it finds an empty column.

I know how to update an empty column but i can`t figurit out how to implement the IF statement.

Until now i have this:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE tabel_name SET ColumnB = 'example' WHERE ColumnA = '$ID' ");
```

Thank You

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use `case` to update only selective columns.

**Example**:

```
update table_name set  
    col1 = ( case when col1 is null then ? else col1 end )  
    , col2 = ( case when col2 is null then ? else col2 end )  
--  , col3 = ...
;
```

Use mysql prepare to replace query parameters.

Also refer to [Quassnoi's answer to a similar posting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6734266/767881).

**Update**:

> *IF ColumnB is not empty then update ColumnC, if ColumnC is not empty update ColumnD ...until it finds an empty column*.

You need to set column values checking in the reverse order.

```
update table_name set  
--      more next ( 4 to n ) columns here if required       
    col3 = ( case when ( col2 is not null and col3 is null ) then 7 else col3 end )  
    , col2 = ( case when ( col1 is not null and col2 is null ) then 8 else col2 end )  
    , col1 = ( case when ( col1 is null ) then 9 else col1 end )  
;
```

**Example Table**:

```
mysql> create table col_values ( id INT, col1 INT, col2 INT, col3 INT );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.06 sec)

mysql> insert into col_values values ( 1, 1, 1, NULL ), ( 2, 1, NULL, NULL ), ( 3, NULL, NULL, NULL );
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.01 sec)
Records: 3  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from col_values;
+------+------+------+------+
| id   | col1 | col2 | col3 |
+------+------+------+------+
|    1 |    1 |    1 | NULL |
|    2 |    1 | NULL | NULL |
|    3 | NULL | NULL | NULL |
+------+------+------+------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> update col_values set
    ->     col3 = ( case when ( col2 is not NULL and col3 is NULL ) then 7 else col3 end )
    ->     , col2 = ( case when ( col1 is not NULL and col2 is NULL ) then 8 else col2 end )
    ->     , col1 = ( case when ( col1 is NULL ) then 9 else col1 end )
    -> ;
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.02 sec)
Rows matched: 3  Changed: 3  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from col_values;
+------+------+------+------+
| id   | col1 | col2 | col3 |
+------+------+------+------+
|    1 |    1 |    1 |    7 |
|    2 |    1 |    8 | NULL |
|    3 |    9 | NULL | NULL |
+------+------+------+------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

You can also use `if` function as an alternative to `case` statement.

```
mysql> truncate table col_values;
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> insert into col_values values ( 1, 1, 1, NULL ), ( 2, 1, NULL, NULL ), ( 3, NULL, NULL, NULL );
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.02 sec)
Records: 3  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from col_values;
+------+------+------+------+
| id   | col1 | col2 | col3 |
+------+------+------+------+
|    1 |    1 |    1 | NULL |
|    2 |    1 | NULL | NULL |
|    3 | NULL | NULL | NULL |
+------+------+------+------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> update col_values set
    ->     col3 = if( ( col2 is not NULL and col3 is NULL ), 7, col3 )
    ->     , col2 = if( ( col1 is not NULL and col2 is NULL ), 8, col2 )
    ->     , col1 = if( col1 is NULL, 9, col1 )
    -> ;
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.01 sec)
Rows matched: 3  Changed: 3  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from col_values;
+------+------+------+------+
| id   | col1 | col2 | col3 |
+------+------+------+------+
|    1 |    1 |    1 |    7 |
|    2 |    1 |    8 | NULL |
|    3 |    9 | NULL | NULL |
+------+------+------+------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, i need to read about the case statement ... to learn it ... the answer below is working

Comment: this will not help OP because if col2 & col3 is NULL, OP want to update only col2 data. Col3 data should be NULL.

Comment: @farkasnorbert : Which answer is working?? Please accept that answer if it is working. See [here, how to accept answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like

```
UPDATE table SET columnC = IF(columnB is not null, "value", columnC) where id = 1
```

Comment: @farkasnorbert : Means you will write same query to update columnD?? `UPDATE table SET columnD = IF(columnC is not null, "value", columnD) where id = 1`

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
    $result=mysql_query('SELECT fav1, fav2, fav3, fav4, fav5 FROM users where id=".."');

    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

      foreach ($row as $columnName=>$value)
      {
         if ($value==null)
            {
             //update users set $columnName=pageID 
             break;
            }
      }
```

Comment: thanks for your answers, something is not working ... let be more specific...what i try to make is an "Add to favourite" script ... i have a table with users ... the table its look like this (ID, UserName, Pasword, Favourite1 Favourite2 Favourite3 Favourite4 Favourite5) ... on every page i have a submit button ... so every user can add 5 favourite pages ... in his account ... so if Favourite1 is not empty go to Favourite2 and store the page_id there ... i have the imput form and is working...I made everything..but i don`t know how to make ...to store in Favourite2 if Favourite1 is not empty