# Update only one column (next column) if previous column is empty

Tags: mysql, if-statement

I have created table and inserted values as below.

```
create table mytable (id INT, col1 INT, col2 INT, col3 INT);

insert into mytable values
(1,1,1,NULL),
(2,1,NULL,NULL);
```

What I want to do is update col2 if col1 is not null, update col3 if col2 is not null and so on... BUT only one column to update.

Consider I want to update data for id=2, then only col2 should be updated and not col2, col3 as both are null.

When I tried with below query, then **all** columns get updated.

```
update myTable set  
      col1 = ( IF (col1 is null, 9, col1) ),
      col2 = ( IF (col2 is null, 9, col2) ),
      col3 = ( IF (col3 is null, 9, col3) );
```

What should be done so that only one column gets updated.

Comment: Your code updates every nul column.. Place the condition on the column before!

Comment: On this damn phone I can t edit comments. For col2 you need to check if col1 is not null before you update, for col3 check col1 amd col 2 and so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems your query is an extension to [*Update MySql Field (if field is not empty, go to next one)*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11176410/update-mysql-field-if-field-is-not-empty-go-to-next-one/11177086#11177086)

You need to set column values checking in the reverse order.

```
update table_name set  
--      more next ( 4 to n ) columns here if required       
    col3 = ( case when ( col2 is not null and col3 is null ) then 7 else col3 end )  
    , col2 = ( case when ( col1 is not null and col2 is null ) then 8 else col2 end )  
    , col1 = ( case when ( col1 is null ) then 9 else col1 end )  
;
```

**Example Table**:

```
mysql> create table col_values ( id INT, col1 INT, col2 INT, col3 INT );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.06 sec)

mysql> insert into col_values values ( 1, 1, 1, NULL ), ( 2, 1, NULL, NULL ), ( 3, NULL, NULL, NULL );
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.01 sec)
Records: 3  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from col_values;
+------+------+------+------+
| id   | col1 | col2 | col3 |
+------+------+------+------+
|    1 |    1 |    1 | NULL |
|    2 |    1 | NULL | NULL |
|    3 | NULL | NULL | NULL |
+------+------+------+------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> update col_values set
    ->     col3 = ( case when ( col2 is not NULL and col3 is NULL ) then 7 else col3 end )
    ->     , col2 = ( case when ( col1 is not NULL and col2 is NULL ) then 8 else col2 end )
    ->     , col1 = ( case when ( col1 is NULL ) then 9 else col1 end )
    -> ;
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.02 sec)
Rows matched: 3  Changed: 3  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from col_values;
+------+------+------+------+
| id   | col1 | col2 | col3 |
+------+------+------+------+
|    1 |    1 |    1 |    7 |
|    2 |    1 |    8 | NULL |
|    3 |    9 | NULL | NULL |
+------+------+------+------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

You can also use `if` function as an alternative to `case` statement.

```
mysql> truncate table col_values;
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> insert into col_values values ( 1, 1, 1, NULL ), ( 2, 1, NULL, NULL ), ( 3, NULL, NULL, NULL );
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.02 sec)
Records: 3  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from col_values;
+------+------+------+------+
| id   | col1 | col2 | col3 |
+------+------+------+------+
|    1 |    1 |    1 | NULL |
|    2 |    1 | NULL | NULL |
|    3 | NULL | NULL | NULL |
+------+------+------+------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> update col_values set
    ->     col3 = if( ( col2 is not NULL and col3 is NULL ), 7, col3 )
    ->     , col2 = if( ( col1 is not NULL and col2 is NULL ), 8, col2 )
    ->     , col1 = if( col1 is NULL, 9, col1 )
    -> ;
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.01 sec)
Rows matched: 3  Changed: 3  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from col_values;
+------+------+------+------+
| id   | col1 | col2 | col3 |
+------+------+------+------+
|    1 |    1 |    1 |    7 |
|    2 |    1 |    8 | NULL |
|    3 |    9 | NULL | NULL |
+------+------+------+------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in two distinct passes, a serial update fashion:

```
UPDATE mytable SET col3 = 9 WHERE col2 IS NOT NULL;
UPDATE mytable SET col2 = 9 WHERE col1 IS NOT NULL;
```

Doing it in this order prevents the cascading of updates across all columns.

Comment: @Saluce The second actually leaves the `col2` to be null and fills `col3`, which is not as expected by the OP. OP wants *update col2 if col1 is not null, update col3 if col2 is not null and so on.*

Comment: @Saluce For the required solution you should do updates in reverse order of columns.

Comment: @saluce No. this update too won't work. It leaves `col2` as `null` and updates `col3` which is not as required. Apart from this, if there are large (`n`) number of columns, then `colN=...`, `colN-1`, ... would be too long, lacks readability and I doubt its performance too.

Comment: @FahimParkar This solution is not correct to update the just next NULL field, say col3, if a field in sequential order, say col2, is not null.

Comment: @saluce Just saw your update. Though updated solutions is not a single query, removed my down vote. :)