# MYSQL CASE WHEN UPDATE Query

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my table.

[image]

What I need to do is create a CASE WHEN UPDATE Query to update

- CurrentCredit +1 if 1-15
- CurrentCredit +2 if 16-30
- CurrentCredit x.10 and round up if >=31

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6734231/mysql-update-case-help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look at the example

### [SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2e3d8/1/0)

Somethign like

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET CurrentCredit = 
CASE 
  WHEN CurrentCredit BETWEEN 1 AND 15
    THEN CurrentCredit + 1
  WHEN CurrentCredit BETWEEN 16 AND 30
    THEN CurrentCredit +2
  WHEN CurrentCredit >= 31
    THEN CurrentCredit * 10
  ELSE CurrentCredit
END
```

Also, remeber that if CurrentCredit is a `FLOAT`, and not an `INT` you might want to try something like

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET CurrentCredit = 
CASE 
  WHEN CurrentCredit >= 1 AND CurrentCredit < 16
    THEN CurrentCredit + 1
  WHEN CurrentCredit >= 16 AND CurrentCredit < 31
    THEN CurrentCredit +2
  WHEN CurrentCredit >= 31
    THEN CurrentCredit * 10
  ELSE CurrentCredit
END;
```

**EDIT**

For the corrected request (>= 31 CurrentCredit + CEILING(CurrentCredit * 0.1)) have a look at using [CEILING](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_ceiling)

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET CurrentCredit = 
CASE 
  WHEN CurrentCredit BETWEEN 1 AND 15
    THEN CurrentCredit + 1
  WHEN CurrentCredit BETWEEN 16 AND 30
    THEN CurrentCredit +2
  WHEN CurrentCredit >= 31
    THEN CurrentCredit + CEILING(CurrentCredit * 0.1)
  ELSE CurrentCredit
END;
```

### [SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/56bdd/1/0)

Comment: @Mahmoud Gamal, I dont think you should delete your answer, it was correct as far as the OP specification went. Just maybe mention the difference.

Comment: I made a mistake on the 31+ credits :-\
It was supposed to be multiply the 31+ credits by 10% then add that number to it but round up.
Any explanation on how to just do that?

Comment: If not that's fine, I understand, you have already been very helpful and I very appreciative.

Comment: @DylanMcCann have a look at the update and using CEILING (which rounds up)