# MYSQL update if not exists else do nothing

Tags: mysql

My question is how do i update a value in a table if it does not exists on another table.I checked [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)
 but it describes about inserting something which updates and not insert.

My situation is like, i have two tables say (t1,t2). I want to update a column in t1 with a value if its not present in t2. Otherwise increment the value and try the update again.
 So i want something like

```
update t1 set column = 'value' if it does not exists in t2
```

Can somebody suggest a solution

Comment: Maybe use of `NOT EXISTS` could work?


    `update t1 set column = 'value' 
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM t2 WHERE column='value')`

This would update the column to same value unless you have another reference key tho.

Comment: Maybe this post can help you : http://stackoverflow.com/a/6734266/1788704

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a way to do it using the JOIN.

```
create table tab1 (id int , val int);
insert into tab1 values (1,1),(2,3),(3,5);

create table tab2 (id int , val int);
insert into tab2  values (4,1),(2,3),(3,5);
```

In the above tab1 (id = 1) not available in tab2 and using the following command we can update such values

```
update tab1 t1
left join tab2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id 
set t1.val = 
  case 
    when t2.id IS NULL then  8 
    else t1.val
  end
```

The output after the update command will look like

```
mysql> select * from tab1 ;
+------+------+
| id   | val  |
+------+------+
|    1 |    8 |
|    2 |    3 |
|    3 |    5 |
+------+------+
```

Also you can use EXIST which is also pretty better than doing left join

```
update tab1 t1 set t1.val = 10
where NOT EXISTS
(
  select 1
  from tab2 where tab2.id = t1.id
)
```

Comment: Which one is faster join or writing sub query inside where condition?

Comment: I always prefer join on indexed columns however sometimes sub-queries also works good if the where condition is done on indexed columns. But as I said I prefer JOIN over sub-query. check here more on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3856164/sql-joins-vs-sql-subqueries-performance