# Update multiple fields on MySQL DB in a single query

Tags: mysql

Here is the structure of my database named employee

```
mysql> desc employee;
+-------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field       | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| emp_code    | int(11)       | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| emp_name    | varchar(25)   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| designation | varchar(25)   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| department  | varchar(25)   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| basic       | decimal(10,2) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| DA          | decimal(10,2) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| gross_pay   | decimal(10,2) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

My question is, how can I update **DA** with value 1500 for rows with **designation** **`manager`** and update **DA** with value 2000 for all other employees.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL update case help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6734231/mysql-update-case-help)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use CASE on update

```
UPDATE  employee
SET     DA =
        CASE
        WHEN designation = 'manager' THEN
                '1500'

        WHEN designation = 'employees' THEN
                '2000'
        END
```

Answer (score 1):

You would use `case` for this purpose:

```
update employees
    set DA = (case when designation = 'manager' then 1500 else 2000 end);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE employee
SET DA = CASE 
WHEN designation = "manager" THEN 1500
ELSE 2000
END
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE employee SET
DA = IF(designation='manager', 1500),
DA = IF(designation='', 1200)
WHERE designation IN('manager', '');
```

Did some research and constructed the above. Try it out, see what happens.

Comment: `IF(designation='', 1200)`, thats the case when it is empty. The OP wants 1200 in **any** other case.

Comment: Aah, I see... so what would go in the place of ' '?

Comment: I'd say `designation<>'manager'`, though i'm not sure if it works like this. (With 2x `DA =`)

Comment: We could throw in an "else" some where I pressume?

Comment: That would make more sence indeed.