# Add more conditions to this update case statement

Tags: mysql

I want to turn this

```
UPDATE table_name
    SET 
    col_1 = CASE id
        WHEN 123 THEN '333'
        WHEN 124 THEN '334'
    END,
    col_2 = CASE id
        WHEN 123 THEN 'blah1'
        WHEN 124 THEN 'blah2'
    END
WHERE id IN (123,124)
```

Into this

```
UPDATE table_name
    SET 
    col_1 = CASE id
        WHEN 123 AND col_3='' AND col_4='' THEN '333'
        WHEN 124 AND col_3='' AND col_4='' THEN '334'
    END,
    col_2 = CASE id
        WHEN 123 AND col_3='' AND col_4='' THEN 'blah1'
        WHEN 124 AND col_3='' AND col_4='' THEN 'blah2'
    END
WHERE id IN (123,124)
```

Or this

```
UPDATE table_name
    SET 
    col_1 = CASE id
        WHEN 123 AND col_3<>'' AND col_4='' THEN '333'
        WHEN 124 AND col_3<>'' AND col_4='' THEN '334'
    END,
    col_2 = CASE id
        WHEN 123 AND col_3<>'' AND col_4='' THEN 'blah1'
        WHEN 124 AND col_3<>'' AND col_4='' THEN 'blah2'
    END
WHERE id IN (123,124)
```

But it's not working.

So for each record, don't update unless certain columns are empty or filled or combination of empty and filled.

Comment: Why not put those conditions in the `WHERE`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL update case help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6734231/mysql-update-case-help)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change syntax of `case id` to `case when id=`

```
UPDATE table_name
    SET 
    col_1 = CASE
        WHEN id=123 AND col_3<>'' AND col_4='' THEN '333'
        WHEN id=124 AND col_3<>'' AND col_4='' THEN '334'
    END,
    col_2 = CASE
        WHEN id=123 AND col_3<>'' AND col_4='' THEN 'blah1'
        WHEN id=124 AND col_3<>'' AND col_4='' THEN 'blah2'
    END
WHERE id IN (123,124)
```

Comment: shouldn't that THEN be like this? THEN col_1='333'

Comment: No. `col_1 = CASE` set field name

Comment: you're right, but having hard time with empty. it's not following the empty rules/conditions, and i don't really want to use NULL. is NULL the only way?

Comment: Not clear understood. You want test null instead empty?

Comment: want to test if empty or if not empty.

Comment: If type of the field is a text (char...), `col_4 <> ""` must work

Comment: what about that "as col_2", why doesn't the first one have it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114655/discussion-between-leoarce-and-splash58).