# Pin/Flag a record in a mysql table to true and the rest to false in a single statement

Tags: mysql, sql

Address Table with 50 records. Has a bool field called "primary_address_indicator".
I want to update a selected record to true and automatically set all other 49 records to false.

I know I can do this with 2 sql statements
First (update all records to false)

```
UPDATE address SET address.primary_address_indicator=0
```

Then (update specific record to true)

```
UPDATE address SET address.primary_address_indicator=1 WHERE address.record_id=31
```

Is there a way to do this in a single sql statement? Something like @Rank?
Keeping it simple... no Unions or some weird self table join.
Maybe what I am looking for does not exist...and that is fine too. just curious.

Comment: can you show some sample data? also mention how a record should be selected for update.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL update case help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6734231/mysql-update-case-help)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update with Case

```
  UPDATE tableName 
         SET Pin = CASE
                   WHEN 1=1      --'your condition' 
                       THEN True
                   ELSE False
                   END
```

PC : [@keWalker](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6734320/4426282)

Comment: This sql statement looks expensive. Seems that the 2 simple updates statements would have less overhead.
But yes, I guess this does the trick, thanks. Will read more about CASE inside queries

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is simply to treat the boolean result as a number:

```
UPDATE address a
    SET a.primary_address_indicator = (a.record_id = 31);
```

`CASE` is the formal way to do it.  This short-hand is specific to MySQL but it is one of the database-specific features that I like.

Comment: So what you are doing is a single update statement that sets all records to the selected record we want to pin. nice.
But now I can not use that column in a sort, to have record 31 as the first record in my displayed table

Comment: @Lixo . . . What is a "displayed table"?  If you have a `select` statement, then you need an `order by` to specify the ordering of the result set.

Comment: I sort by primary_address_indicator asc, and then by record_seq_num and then I display the result in a html table.
So that the pin record is always displayed first regardless of how the other columns are sorted and then. Thanks, I am good now, I see several ways of getting what I need done. :)