# How do I update multiple data using single query?

Tags: php, mysql

This query takes a lot of time to run when the id_array is big. How can I make it faster? Is it maybe possible to do this in one query instead of multiple updates as in my example?

```
<?php
$sort = 1;
$id_array = array(
    56,
    14,
    99,
    54,
    8,
    92
);
foreach ($id_array as $id) {
    mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE id_table SET sort = '$sort' WHERE id = '$id'");
    $sort++;
}
?>
```

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6734231/mysql-update-case-help

Comment: you should use `where in` for these type of query

Comment: Sougata, the solution at the link you gave me works perfect.

Answer (score 3):

Legend has it that using a `prepared statement` can be quicker than other types of query when dealing with large datasets - whether this is true or not is for you to decide - but to use a prepared statement you could try like this:

```
$sql='update id_table set sort = ? where id = ?';
$stmt=$conn->prepare( $sql );
$stmt->bind_param( 'ii', $sort, $id );

foreach( $id_array as $index => $id ){
    $sort=$index+1;
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

assuming you have an array as

```
$id_array = array(56, 14, 99, 54, 8, 92);
```

and you db driver allow multiple sql statement 
you could try using sql var   a in clause and avoid loop ( avoid also quote for numeric values ) building a proper string for IN clause

```
$yourArray = implode(', ', $id_array);

mysqli_query($conn, " set  @sort = 0;
 UPDATE id_table SET sort = @sort +1 WHERE id IN  ( ". $your_Array . ")");
```

Comment: It feels wrong to use internal variables here, but maybe it's just a feeling

Comment: I can't get this to work. It feels like a simple solution but sort is not incremented when I run this query.

Answer (score 0):

This is my final solution. It works great and is much faster than my first attempt.

```
$sort = 1;
$query = "UPDATE id_table SET sort = CASE ";
foreach($id_array as $id)
    {
    $query = $query . "WHEN id = '$id' THEN '$sort' ";  
    $sort++;
    }
$query = $query . "END";
mysqli_query($conn, $query);
```